# Yforms in hybris

Tags: forms, sap-commerce-cloud

I was going through forms which are created in Financial Accelerator Service, I debug all the flow and understand that these forms are coming 
through impex. Template, component, slot are created in impex for that.

But I have few doubts:

1. Where these yform data are stored(persist) in hybris? I did not find where forms data are getting saved.
2. If I need to create a dynamic yform then what will be procedure? Will I create a item type for that or not. How I will store data of form in hybris?

Answer (score 0):

> Where these yform data are stored(persist) in hybris? I did not find
>   where forms data are getting saved.

Refer `DefaultYFormService.java`, where you will find all `YFormDefinition`/`YFormData` operations. Form data will stored in `YFormData` table using `YFormDataModel` you can see `updateYFormData` method.

> If I need to create a dynamic yform then what will be procedure? Will
>   I create a item type for that or not. How I will store data of form in
>   hybris?

From [backoffice](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Creating+new+yForms+in+Backoffice) you can create & publish yform dynamically. You need to create instance of `YFormDefinitionModel` not an itemtype. [Adding New yForms in Backoffice](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Creating+new+yForms+in+Backoffice#CreatingnewyFormsinBackoffice-AddingNewyFormsinBackoffice).